# Trying to Implement SAML 2.0 with ColdFusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, saml-2.0, cfml, coldfusion-11

Message

> Could not find a resolver for URI 57B9D321-DB61-06DF-FCD55B10E90EC81F and Base
>   RootCause
>   Cause
>   Message   Could not find a resolver for URI 57B9D321-DB61-06DF-FCD55B10E90EC81F and Base
>    MsgID    utils.resolver.noClass

This is the error which I am getting. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We will need more information to help you. See [ask] for some guidance.

Comment: Where do you get this error?

Comment: This is the line on which I am getting error: signature.sign(key);

Comment: And I am trying to implement the code as suggested in this blog http://blog.tagworldwide.com/?p=19

Comment: Entire code is in one .cfm page and at last line "signature.sign(key);" i am getting error. If I comment it I am able to see base 64 encoded SAML in cfdump.

Comment: Please use the edit link to add those details to your question.